# Accessing complex json data in angularjs

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I am trying to display json data in html form using ng-repeat, I was able to grab data but some I could not due to objects in objects structure. Ex : "Obj  => Obj  =>  Obj" of a kind.

In the json object below, I have accessed the objs in the "Color" but where I need help is to access the objs in the "seat" and "engine"!. I think whatever ng-repeat that grabs "seat" objs would likely do the same for the "engine".

I did like this: `ng-repeat = "c in datasource"` first step. Next in a td, I did `ng-repeat =" allcolor in c.Color"` to get data of that "Color".

Now in another td, I want to grab the data of objs in "seat", how do I go about it?

Ex: `ng-repeat = "seatobjs in allcolor.seat"` not working.

```
<tr ng-repeat = "c in datasource">
<td>{{c.Name}}</td>
<td>{{c.From}}</td>
<td ><p ng-repeat="allcolor in c.Color> 
     {{allcolor.Name}}</p></td>
<td><p ng-repeat="seatobjs in allcolor.seat"> //need help here
     {{seatobjs.Name}}</p></td>
<td><button type="button" ng-disabled="!(check)">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

Thank

```
[ 
   { 
    "Name": "Car",
    "From": "2019-06-26", 
    "Tom": "2019-12-31",
    "Color": [ 
        { 
            "Name": "Green",             
            "From": "2019-06-26",  
            "Tom": "2019-12-31",
            "seat": [ 
              { 
                "Name": "Yello",                  
                "From": "2019-06-26", 
                "Tom": "2019-12-31"
              },
              { 
                "Name": "Green",              
                "From": "2019-06-26", 
                "Tom": "2019-12-31"
              }
            ],
            "engine": [     
              { 
                "Name": "Brown",                 
                "From": "2019-06-26", 
                "Tom": "2019-12-31"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
   },
   { 
    "Name": "Car",
    "From": "2019-06-26", 
    "Tom": "2019-12-31",
    "Color": [     
        { 
            "Name": "Red",             
            "From": "2019-06-26", 
            "Tom": "2019-12-31",
            "tyre": [       
              { 
                "Name": "Yello",                  
                "From": "2019-06-26", 
                "Tom": "2019-12-31"
              },
              { 
                "Name": "Green",              
                "From": "2019-06-26", 
                "Tom": "2019-12-31"
              }
            ],
            "engine": [ 
              { 
                "Name": "Black",                 
                "From": "2019-06-26", 
                "Tom": "2019-12-31"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
   },
]
```

Comment: That JSON is not valid!

Comment: It was an example, why is it not valid?

Comment: engine is not closed by ]

Comment: `engine` looks like it is supposed to be an array but is missing the closing bracket `]`. There is a trailing comma after the last item in the top level array

Comment: Guys, the thing is, how do I access data, though I have closed the engine, lets overlook the json.

Comment: Please show us your html markup

Comment: Map your data in controller before sending to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allcolor` cannot be accessed by elements that are outside of the `ng-repeat` defined element. 
With your given HTML markup, you might want to use ng-repeat again on the new td and access seat as follows.

```
<tr ng-repeat = "c in datasource">
    <td>{{c.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{c.From}}</td>
    <td ><p ng-repeat="allcolor in c.Color> 
        {{allcolor.Name}}</p>
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat =" allcolor2 in c.Color">
        <p ng-repeat="seatobjs in allcolor2.seat">{{seatobjs.Name}}</p>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" ng-disabled="!(check)">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ng-repeat = "seatobjs in allcolor['seat']"
```

Comment: allcolor is in a separate td you can't access it in another td. I suggest, you may use allcolor in another variable in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive you can iterate over the properties of an object. This is the syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj">…</div>
```

The following code iterates some properties of your JSON and binds them inside a table:

```js
var carApp = angular.module('carApp', []);
carApp.controller('CarController', function CarController($scope) {
  $scope.cars = [{
      "Name": "Car",
      "From": "2019-06-26",
      "Tom": "2019-12-31",
      "Color": [{
        "Name": "Green",
        "From": "2019-06-26",
        "Tom": "2019-12-31",
        "seat": [{
            "Name": "Yello",
            "From": "2019-06-26",
            "Tom": "2019-12-31"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Green",
            "From": "2019-06-26",
            "Tom": "2019-12-31"
          }
        ],
        "engine": [{
          "Name": "Brown",
          "From": "2019-06-26",
          "Tom": "2019-12-31"
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Car",
      "From": "2019-06-26",
      "Tom": "2019-12-31",
      "Color": [{
        "Name": "Red",
        "From": "2019-06-26",
        "Tom": "2019-12-31",
        "tyre": [{
            "Name": "Yello",
            "From": "2019-06-26",
            "Tom": "2019-12-31"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Green",
            "From": "2019-06-26",
            "Tom": "2019-12-31"
          }
        ],
        "engine": [{
          "Name": "Black",
          "From": "2019-06-26",
          "Tom": "2019-12-31"
        }]
      }]
    },
  ];
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="carApp">
  <div ng-controller="CarController">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Seat</th>
          <th>Tyre</th>
          <th>Engine</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
          <td>{{car.Name}}</td>
          <td>
            <span>{{car.Color[0].Name}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="seat in car.Color[0].seat">{{seat.Name}}</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="tyre in car.Color[0].tyre">{{tyre.Name}}</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td>{{car.Color[0].engine[0].Name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```